# Run PHP script with Upstart after reboot

Tags: php, ubuntu, upstart

I have the following Upstart script. When I run the following command `service worker-1 start`, everything works perfect. I can see running workers with `ps aux | grep php`. I can also use `service worker-1 stop` which I need to restart/update workers. But unfortunately this script works only partially on reboot. The script is executed (start: Job is already running: worker-1 when I try `service worker-1 start`) but I do not see any running workers with `ps aux | grep php` and of course `service worker-1 stop` returns `stop: Unknown instance:`. Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

```
description "Starts/kills workers."
author "Jiri Mihal"
start on (started php5-fpm and started mysql)
stop on shutdown

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Workers started" >> /var/log/worker-1.log
    exec 2>>/var/log/worker-1.log
end script

post-start script
    echo $$ > /var/run/worker-1.pid
    for i in `seq 1 5`;
    do
        exec php /home/jiri/workers/dlapi.workers/workers/RpcWorkerLauncher.php Worker-1 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    done
end script

post-stop script
    read -r FIRSTLINE < /var/run/worker-1.pid
    kill $(($FIRSTLINE + 2))
    kill $(($FIRSTLINE + 3))
    kill $(($FIRSTLINE + 4))
    kill $(($FIRSTLINE + 5))
    kill $(($FIRSTLINE + 6))
    rm /var/run/worker-1.pid
    echo "[`date`] Workers stopped" >> /var/log/worker-1.log
end script
```

Comment: Just a guess, but on restart I would assume the user running the startup script/service is not you and is likely root. Have you tried running the command using sudo or even su to root and run it.

Comment: Yes I tried it and I can run above commands with sudo without any issues. I can also run these commands as root user. But I can try to change path from user's folder to some 'system' folder. Maybe user's folder is not available early on startup.

Comment: Try using something like this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/20229/how-to-run-an-application-at-startup-as-a-certain-user) to switch the user on boot to another user (yourself) and run the startup command/service under that user.

Comment: @Mihi as a note: sudo is functionally the same as root user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script above is almost correct. The main problem was that PHP script initiated RabbitMQ worker but RabbitMQ server was not ready.

I made some additional tweaks and here is a working solution:

```
description "Starts/kills workers."
author "Jiri Mihal"
start on (rabbitmq-server-running or started rabbitmq-server)
stop on (shutdown or rabbitmq-server-stopped or stopping rabbitmq-server)

env WORKER=Workername
env COUNT=5

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Workers started" >> /var/log/worker-$WORKER.log
end script

post-start script
    for i in `seq 1 $COUNT`;
    do
        exec php /home/jiri/workers/dlapi.workers/workers/RpcWorkerLauncher.php $WORKER >/dev/null 2>&1 &
        if [ $i = 1 ]; then
           echo $! > /var/run/worker-$WORKER.pid
        fi
    done
end script

post-stop script
    read -r PID < /var/run/worker-$WORKER.pid
    for i in `seq 1 $COUNT`;
    do
        kill $(($PID + $i - 1))
    done
    rm /var/run/worker-$WORKER.pid
    echo "[`date`] Workers stopped" >> /var/log/worker-$WORKER.log
end script
```